# How to find the initial temperature?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

I am stuck in the given problem hope u can help me:

Some hot water was added to three times its mass of water at 100 C and the resulting temperature was 200 C. What was the temperature of the hot water?

Comment: I wonder if perhaps you meant 10°C and 20°C and it somehow became 100C and 200C... because as written your question makes little sense - you would need to make assumptions about phase transitions that are clearly beyond your current level of physics. Could you take another look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course water above 100°C will become vapor (steam) at atmospheric pressure, but it's still "water" in the sense of a substance. So ignoring for a moment questions of the state of matter of the water, the "textbook" solution is simple: assuming a constant heat capacity $c$ for the water (independent of temperature, and specifically assuming there are no phase transitions which really mess with the calculation), if you have $3M$ at $T_1$ and add $M$ at $T_2$, the resulting temperature $T_3$is found from

$$3M(T_3-T_1) = M(T_2-T_3)\\
T_2=4 T_3 - 3 T_1$$

When $T_1$ = 100°C and $T_3$ = 200°C, it follows that $T_2$ = 500°C.

That's above the critical temperature for water, so we're definitely dealing with water in the vapor phase. Now whether the initial water was vapor or liquid was not specified in the problem.

I admit to being puzzled at the phrasing of the question. Could it be that you meant 10°C and 20°C? It would be an easy transcription error and would make a LOT more sense...

Comment: Putting a chunk of the question into Google Books yields https://books.google.ca/books?id=eyFw4unYnhAC&pg=PA205&dq=%22water+was+added+to+three+times+its+mass+of+water&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-_mhVNDVIpasyAS-hoKgAw&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA

Indeed , there are some decimal points missing...

Comment: @Floris according to your analogy T2 should be 500C. How can it be 700C??

Comment: @zafri you are right - I tried to do the math in my head... Fixed now. Thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

First of all your question is **wrong**. Lets see where it went wrong exactly!

First things first, lets say you have $x$ water at $100 ^\circ C$. Then when you add more energy to it, the temperature of water will still remain $100 ^\circ C$, but the extra energy will be used to convert water at $100 ^\circ C$ to steam at $100 ^\circ C$(phase change), and then that steam, will gain extra energy as I pump more energy to my system.

So you saying that water being added to water at $100 ^\circ C$, and then the temperate being $200 ^\circ C$, is bit of a nonsense!

**Note**: I have assumed pressure to be 1 atmosphere atleast.

Comment: I think you would need to point out that if water is present at temperatures above 100°C, then the pressure must be above atmospheric or the water is in the form of steam (water vaport), rather than saying the question is "wrong".

Comment: @Floris: I do imply that the pressure is atleast 1 atmosphere. Ofcourse by ignoring the state, one could write the simple expression that you wrote and solve for $T_2$.